# How to display VSD Stored in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mime

I'm trying to display a VSD ( Visio document ) in a web-page; my problem is that I'm saving the contents of the VSD in an SQL table.

I store a few images in this table already, and can display most of them fine, but since the VSD does not have a 'mime' type that can be derived from getimagesize, I'm not sure what kind of header to send back to my client.

Does anyone have any experience doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If all you're looking for is a MIME type, check out [this page](http://filext.com/file-extension/VSD). There's a list of MIME types you can try.

Comment: Helpful, and did point me at the 'image/x-vsd' type; but chrome doesn't seem to want anything to do with this, or any of the other types listed on that page.